# ThreeJS: OrbitControls not working if TransformControls is present in r95

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a sample code [here](https://codepen.io/ccamilo/pen/QBZexb). In my project used to work just fine before getting r95 version.

Basically, the function "onMouseMove" from OrbitControls is never reached. So you can only zoom but not pan or rotate.

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
(...)
// adding transformControl makes OrbitControls stop working
var transformControl = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
```

If I use EditorControls instead of OrbitControls then it works, but problem with EditorControls is that you cannot configure the mouse buttons (unless you change the code).

Is there any reason for this or any workaround?

Comment: This is a three.js bug. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14619.